# Nested Form / Mapping field to entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm looking for best (or just working) way to solve following problem.
I have like standard UserType form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            'username',
            Type\TextType::class
        )
        ->add(
            'email',
            Type\EmailType::class
        )
        ->add(
            'plainPassword',
            Security\UserRepeatedPasswordType::class
        )
        ->add(
            'roles',
            Type\ChoiceType::class,
            [
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'choices' => $this->getRoleChoices()
            ]
        );
}
```

What is *nonstandard* is that `UserRepeatedPasswordType`, it looks like this

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            'password',
            Type\RepeatedType::class,
            [
                'type' => Type\PasswordType::class,
                'required' => true,
                'first_options'  => [
                    'label' => 'Password'
                ],
                'second_options' => [
                    'label' => 'Repeat Password'
                ],
            ]
        );
}
```

And I created it because those two fields are also used in passwordReset form and userSettings form. And now I have two problems:

1.) When I use it this way, value from `UserRepeatedPasswordType` is not correctly mapped for my `User` Entity - there is an error that string is expected (duh ;) but it got array. I tried using View and Model transformer but no proper results (but I don't have much experience with those, so that maybe the case). I also tried to experiment with `getParent()`, and pass there `UserType` but it goes to some endless loop and I got 500. If I just copy paste field from `UserRepeatedPasswordType` to `UserType` it works correctly.

2.) If this is solved (or even by copy paste, if can't be done other way), there is another related (I believe) problem:

I have this `ChangePasswordType` form, which is used to reset your password.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            'confirmationToken',
            Type\HiddenType::class,
            [
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ]
            ]
        )
        ->add(
            'plainPassword',
            Type\RepeatedType::class,
            [
                'type' => Type\PasswordType::class,
                'required' => true,
                'first_options'  => [
                    'label' => 'Password'
                ],
                'second_options' => [
                    'label' => 'Repeat Password'
                ],
            ]
        )
        ->add(
            'changePassword',
            Type\SubmitType::class
        );
}
```

And it works fine as it is but I want to do two things with it - first, solving my first problem and use `UserRepeatedPasswordType` in it, second - I have some `Assert\Length` done in `User` Entity on `$plainPassword` and it workes correctly when I submit new user via UserType form. But I want that validation somewhat mapped to `ChangePasswordType` or ideally to `UserRepeatedPasswordType` - just to have all rules in one place. Can this even be done? Thanks for any solutions / hints / advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, dunno if anyone is interested but that is how I completed this. If anyone have better answer, just give me a sign (mostly to the first one) ;)

1.) As i thought, solved by ViewTransformer but in parent form (In `UserType` not in `UserRepeatedPasswordType`

```
$builder->get('plainPassword')
    ->addViewTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($singleAsArray) {
            return $singleAsArray;
        },
        function ($arrayAsSingle) {
            return $arrayAsSingle['password'] ?? '';
        }
    ));
```

2.) That was actually quite easy. All you have to do is to map that form to UserEntity that same way as `UserType` and made custom validation groups just to have everything nice and under control :)